# plot not working while simulating a time series

Tags: r, plot, time-series, simulate

I'm trying to simulate a time serie in R

```
x = vector()
simul = rnorm(0,1,n=100)
for(t in (1:100))
{
    x[t] = t/5 + cos(2*t*pi/10)+simul[t]
}

plot(x)
```

**ERROR :**

**Error in plot.window(...) : finite values required for 'ylim'**

**In addition: Warning messages:**

**1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf**

**2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf**

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error either. @Amine, could you put 'set.seed(123)' before creating the random numbers. Then we are on the same page, as it will create always the same numbers.

Comment: It's working. I forgot to add specifty n in rnorm :p

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question does not generate an error when I run it.  Note that to be reproducible you need to set the random seed.  Also there is no need for a loop.  It could be written more compactly like this:

```
set.seed(123)

t <- seq_len(100)
x <- t/5 + cos(2*t*pi/10) + rnorm(100)
plot(x)
```